# My google calendar events do not show up in my drop down calaendar

Tags: gnome, calendar, google-calendar

I am running Ubuntu 21.10.

I have added my google account and enabled calendar sync.

When click the datetime display in the top center of my desktop, it show s dropdown calendar. This calendar does not show any of my google calendar events. If I open the calendar app, the events do show up, but not in the dropdown calendar.

Comment: You logged out then back in? Restarted the system in the mean time?